# Windows Phone Link audio quality

Tags: windows-10, windows-11, microsoft-phone-link

I tried using Windows Phone Link with my Samsung S21 and now also with Samsung S23+. Both on Windows 10 Professional and Windows 11 Professional. Former is a HP Elite desk 800 mini PC with integrated Bluetooth adapter and the latter is a new HP Desktop computer with a Wi-Fi 6 Bluetooth 5.2 PCIe Adapter.

I'm using classic/cable USB connected headphones with microphone on both computers. Headset works perfectly when making call via Skype, MS Teams, Zoom or Viber.

But, the sound is very low. Not so much on my side, but the people I'm talking to are saying they can barely here and/or there is much interference.

I'm presuming this has to the with the fact that Phone link uses Bluetooth to transfer voice and there is no possibility to do it via Wi-Fi or USB cable.

Is there any way to use Phone link via direct USB cable connection or Wi-Fi instead of Bluetooth?

Comment: from https://answers.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/forum/all/when-using-the-your-phone-app-mic-issue/660756ba-6e8c-452b-b114-ef7f4530accf : Go to PC's microphone settings,  "Additional device properties", "Advanced" tab, "Signal Enhancements"... *uncheck* "Allow extra signal processing by the audio device* (echo cancellation) and set mic gain manually. See also https://www.elevenforum.com/t/trouble-with-microsoft-link-to-windows-on-windows-11.15722/

Comment: @DrMoishePippik: thank you, but both of the links you provided relate to an issue when mic is not working at all. In my case it is working, it's just that the sound quality is very poor (compared to skype, viber, teams etc.).